# SIMD-exploiting implementation of Peterson and Monico's Lanczos algorithm over the field with two elements

Tags: algorithm, simd, lanczos

(This question is probably flirting with the "no software recommendations" rule; I understand why it might be closed).

In their paper *[F_2 Lanczos revisited](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379507004211)*, Peterson and Monico give a version of the Lanczos algorithm for finding a subspace of the kernel of a linear map over Z/2Z. If my cursory reading of their paper is correct (whether it is or not is clearly not a question for SO), the algorithm presented requires a number of iterations that scales inversely proportional to the word size of the machine used. The authors implemented their proof of concept algorithm with a 64 bit word size.

Does there exist a publicly available implementation of that algorithm utilizing wide SIMD words for (a potentially significant) speedup?

Answer (score 0):

An existing implementation would be a software recommendation. A more interesting question is "Is it possible to use SIMD to make this algorithm run faster?" From my glance at the paper, it sounds like SIMD is exactly what they are describing ("We will partition a 64 bit machine word x into eight subwords...where each ... is an 8-bit word") so if the authors' implementation is publicly available somewhere, the answer is "yes" because they're already using it. If this algorithm were written in C/C++ or something like that, an optimizing compiler would likely do a pretty good job of vectorizing it with SIMD even without manually specifying how to split the registers (can be verified by looking at the assembly). It would arguably be preferable to implement in high level language without splitting registers manually, because then the compiler could optimize it for any target machine's word size.